# laravel 5.4 how to make page title with dynamic

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-5.4

ihave a route to get artists initial letter.

this is my route

```
Route::get('/artists/{letter}', 'HomeController@showArtist')->where('letter', '[A-Za-z]+')->name('list');
```

and this is my controller showArtist method

```
public function showArtist($letter){
        $artists = Artist::where('name', 'like', $letter.'%')->get();
        return view('front.list',compact('artists'));
    }
```

what i want is in my list page that lists all artists alphabetically, i have made alphabetical menu like this A B C, FOR example if is clicked it will get all artists with initial letter A.

but my question is how can i make in my page title, foreaxmple like this "Artists begging with letter A" etc.

@section('title', 'artists begging with'. $artist->letter)

my question is how to find letter value?

please help how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass selected letter value to Blade view like this:

```
return view('front.list',compact('artists','letter'));
```

instead of:

```
return view('front.list',compact('artists'));
```

And now in your view you can use:

```
<title>Artists begging with {{ $letter }}</title>
```

Comment: Perfect it worked as you mentioned. Thank u very much for your help

Answer (score 23):

If this is your master page title below

```
<head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
    </head>
```

then your page title can be changed in your blade page like below

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Page Title')

@section('sidebar')
@parent

<p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@endsection

@section('content')
<p>This is my body content.</p>
@endsection
```

Comment: If the title hasn't been set in your blade page, a dash will awkwardly show at the end of the 'App Name'. If this is a problem for you, use something like this in your master page layout: `@if(View::hasSection('title'))@yield('title') - @endif{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}`.

Comment: Additionally, if your application supports multiple languages, doing `@section('title', 'Page Title')` may not be an option. To use Laravel's language translation features with the `@section` directive simply call `trans()` like so: `@section('title', trans('feature.title'))`.

Answer (score 0):

First step : Add this code inside header Tag.

```
 <title> Website Name ( optional ) - @yield('title')</title>
```

Second Step : Add below code inside dynamic Page.

```
@section('title',  $data['metaTitle'])
```